# Logcat on Huawei Honor 8? Background Debug Password?

Tags: android, passwords, logcat, huawei-mobile-services

recently I aquired a Honor 8 and updated it to EMUI 5. When I started testing my projects, I noticed that nothing was shown at the logcat, i searched and it was a common problem in Huawei Smartphones that can be solved by dialing `*#*#2846579#*#*`, then goiing into Background setting->Log settings, activating the App log and restarting the device.

The problem is that this method doesn't work in my case (neither if I don't restart the device). I figured that it was because when I went to the Background debug, it appears to be closed, but when I hit on open it asks for a password.

Anyone knows what the password is or how can I manage to activate the ApLog?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find any answer?

Comment: @AanalMehta Yes. Well, kind of. It appears to be a system file, that I don't remember it's exact location. But you need to have your phone rooted to erase or modify that file. Anyhow, what I did is that I installed LineageOS and used it for a while, then I got tired of it and I returned to EMUI and the problem was solved. Apparently, deleting the whole OS, erases that file too. Good luck with the issue!